# Remove xtick and ytick but keep grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, subplot

I'm trying to remove the xtick and ytick so that the final diagram looks like below. I want to keep the guide lines so that it would be easier for referencing. However, in Matplotlib, once you remove the xtick or ytick using the `ax.set_xticks([])` or `ax.set_yticks([])` method, the grid also disappears. Is there a way to make the `plt.grid()` function not infer from the xticks or yticks? Any suggestion is much appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the visibilty:

```
xticklines = ax.get_xticklines()
for i in xticklines:
    i.set_visible(False)
```